# date array to week array and sum of values

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am looking into converting an array of dates and data into an array of week start date and the sum of the data for the contained days in those weeks.

here is what i have and what I want to have :

```
//array coming from some other process (mysql)    
    $data = array(
      array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/12', 'value' => '2'), //sunday
      array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/13', 'value' => '3'), //monday
      array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/14', 'value' => '4'), //tuesday
      array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/15', 'value' => '3'), //wednesday
      array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/20', 'value' => '2'), //monday
      array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/21', 'value' => '3'), //tuesday
      array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/22', 'value' => '2'), //wendesday
      array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/23', 'value' => '4'), //thursday
    );

    $starts = 'Sunday';
    //week starts on sunday  (need to be able to define this, for example this could be monday)

    //expected output array :
    $data_weekly = array(
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/12', 'value' => '12'), //sunday and addition of values for that week starting on sunday
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/19', 'value' => '11'), //sunday and addition of values for that week starting on sunday
    );
```

Not sure what the best way to do this would be. Should I start collecting yearweek in a loop and start summing up values to produce the second array? or is there a better more efficient way or native function?

Comment: So how is the `$data` array created?

Comment: very long story.. it is coming from a mysql database after many many loops and processes and outputs to json that is parsed using JS for a datatable. i need to have a "week" switcher on this datatable, so I figured the best would be to modify the end array just before the json to produce an alternative json rather than do it in the mysql or using JS in the datatable..

Comment: May I suggest that that _back at the MYSQL collection phase_ is where you should be looking

Comment: The thing is that this page has 30 tables, so there are 30 different mysql queries I will need to create/modify  and hook up above as the values are all sorts of different metrics (I just simplified it for my example) also there are 5 more pages with less tables but same output format, so if i had a single function to modify this as above would be better i think so I am not lost when I need to revise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution can be turned into a two-liner wrapped in a foreach loop, but it wouldn't be very readable.  I have explained in comments, but if you have questions about it, feel free to ask me.

Here is the code with comments:

```
$data = array(
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/12', 'value' => '2'), //sunday
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/13', 'value' => '3'), //monday
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/14', 'value' => '4'), //tuesday
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/15', 'value' => '3'), //wednesday
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/20', 'value' => '2'), //monday
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/21', 'value' => '3'), //tuesday
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/22', 'value' => '2'), //wendesday
    array('product' => 'test', 'date' => '2017/02/23', 'value' => '4'), //thursday
);

// str_to_time() likes to deal with date in YYYY-MM-DD format
foreach($data as $row){
    if(date('w',strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$row["date"])))==0){
        // this is a Sunday
        $key=$row["date"];
    }else{
        // this is not a Sunday, get last Sunday
        $key=date("Y/m/d",strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$row["date"])." last Sunday")); 
    }
    if(!isset($result[$key])){
        // initialize the subarray
        $result[$key]=$row;
    }else{
        // add the new value to running value tally
        $result[$key]["value"]+=$row["value"];
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_export($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Here is the output:

```
array(
    '2017/02/12' => array(
        'product' => 'test',
        'date' => '2017/02/12',
        'value' => 12
     ),
     '2017/02/19' => array(
        'product' => 'test',
        'date' => '2017/02/20',
        'value' => 11
     )
)
```